# Start process and wait until logfile has specific entry

Tags: bash, process, kill

I want to start a process in a bash script like this:

```
myProcess -p someparameter > log.txt &
```

And then I want to stop the process as soon as `log.txt` contains `defined sentence to wait for`. **So I am NOT waiting for a file, but for an entry in a logfile!**

What is the best way to do that (without frying my processors, hence no loops which run like crazy)?

Comment: How fast does the output get written to the log file? At what frequency?

Comment: Not very fast. It is more the state of calculations. Varying from something like 10 lines per second down to a line every 20 seconds. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Have you tried piping through `grep -q` and `tee`? `myProcess -p someparameter | tee log.txt | grep -q 'defined sentence to wait'`.

Comment: @Michael This can never work stable. Forget it!

Comment: @hek2mgl: Why do you think it might not produce a buffered output? and what else might have been wrong?

Comment: @hek2mgl Why can it not be stable in my case? As soon as I see this entry in the log file I know that some file is written and I can retrieve this then. Or to which solution are you refering to?

Comment: The problem is that *as soon as logfile contains XY* is a pretty undefined moment in time and does not say anything about the state of the process at that time. The process will likely have continued doing other things at the moment the watchdog detects the message in the logfile.

Comment: If the line indicates that a file has been written, you might be better off checking for the existence of that file rather than the presence of the line in the log.

Comment: How would you check for the existence of the file? But still, might be more secure to check for the entry in the log file, since then I know the file has been written and closed.

Comment: @VarunM Better approach, but even that would not guarantee that the process has stepped forward already. Also if the process, let's say a shell script, writes like `echo 1 > file; echo 2 >> file` it is hard to say when the file is complete.

Comment: IMO the only clean solution is to fix that process itself and let it stop at the right moment.

Comment: The whole thing is about doing an automated analysis for one time on about 50 different inputs. Job done. It is not an academic exercise :-D But thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments I expressed my concerns about the stability of such a solution because the process might already have been stepped further at the moment the watchdog detects the message in the logfile.

You said to that: `The whole thing is about doing an automated analysis for one time on about 50 different inputs. Job done. It is not an academic exercise`.

Ok, for such an use case you can do the following:

```
# Use stdbuf -oL to make sure the process output
# will get line buffered (instead of default block-buffered)
stdbuf -oL ./process -p param > logfile &
pid=$!

# Again make sure that the output of tail get's
# line buffered. grep -m1 stops after the first
# occurence
stdbuf -oL tail -f logfile | grep -m1 "PATTERN" && kill "${pid}"
```

Note: I suppose that `process` will exit nicely on `kill` in this example.

Comment: works for me, thanks